# Physical states of a non-relativistic Majorana fermion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, majorana-fermions

Would it be correct to say that the space of all possible physical states of a non-relativistic Majorana fermion is a circle? (analogous to the Bloch sphere in the case of a regular two-level system)  That's what I get when enforcing the spinor to be real.

Answer (score 1):

No. Even if you cook it down to a two-dimensional object (which you can't in the Majorana representation) it will still transform with an SU(2) matrix under rotations. It is certainly not the orbit of a U(1).